# interpolating quaternions at two different times

Tags: math, eigen, quaternions

I have two quaternions at two different times.

```
q1 t1

q2 t2
```

I want to find the quaternion in between them at time t_inter by interpolating.

Would it be correct to do:

```
q_intermediate = slerp(q1,q2, (t_inter-t1)/(t2-t1))
```

?

I understand slerp takes the percent difference between the times.

EDIT::
I mean the slerp mathematical function defined here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp

Comment: What language/library is `slerp` in? You should add the appropriate tag.

Comment: It can be in any language that has the appropriate function. It is not a question about the function, it is a question about the mathematical process

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:eigen]? Are you referring to the C++ library Eigen, and how to do slerp there?

Comment: Relevant article: [Understanding Slerp, Then Not Using It](http://number-none.com/product/Understanding%20Slerp,%20Then%20Not%20Using%20It/)

Comment: Interesting article, @chtz. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear.

If your question really means "*is it OK to use [`slerp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) interpolation for my particular problem*", it is impossible to answer unless you specify your problem.

If your question really means "*I want to use [`slerp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) interpolation but it takes parameter `t` in range `[0, 1]`. Is this the correct way to map my `t_inter` in the range `[t1, t2]` to that range?*" then the answer is ***yes***, this is the right way.